# Eloquent Relation not returning errors or result

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The following code does not return any error:

```
$exchange = Exchange::findOrFail(16);
dd($exchange->values);
```

The `Exchange` model has the following relation:

`return $this->belongsTo(ExchangeValue::class, 'value', 'exchange_id');`

The database schema is:

exchanges (id, type, title, description)
exchange_values (id, exchange_id, value)

Of course I've specified the database table in the `ExchangeValue` model because it doesn't follow the Laravel convention.

I have a record in the database with `exchange_id 16` and it's returning `null`, without a query error or something.

What could be the issue?

Comment: What's the second argument, `'value'`, doing? Shouldn't the foreign key come second?

Comment: exchange_id should be you second argument in belongsTo..